# Rails: Send email with embedded image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sending an email with an image embedded inside the email:

```
<a href="#"><%= image_tag "/images/logo.png", width: 94, height: 40 %></a>
```

Now, the weird part is that I can see image if I open the email from my mac, but if open it form a  mobile device I cant see the image.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Update 1**

this is the mailer action:

```
def new_user_notification(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: @user.email, subject: "Welcome"
end
```

and this the email view template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
      table[class=body] h1 {
        font-size: 28px !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
      }
      table[class=body] p,
      table[class=body] ul,
      table[class=body] ol,
      table[class=body] td,
      table[class=body] span,
      table[class=body] a {

      }
      table[class=body] .wrapper,
      table[class=body] .article {
        padding: 10px !important;
      }
      table[class=body] .content {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
      table[class=body] .container {
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table[class=body] .main {
        border-left-width: 0 !important;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        border-right-width: 0 !important;
      }
      table[class=body] .btn table {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table[class=body] .btn a {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table[class=body] .img-responsive {
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: auto !important;
      }
    }


    @media all {
      .ExternalClass {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass div {
        line-height: 100%;
      }
      .apple-link a {
        color: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      .btn-primary table td:hover {
        background-color: #34495e !important;
      }
      .btn-primary a:hover {
        background-color: #34495e !important;
        border-color: #34495e !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
 </head>
<body class="" style="background-color: #f6f6f6; font-family: sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="container" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block; Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px; padding: 10px; width: 580px;">
       <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 580px; padding: 10px;">

        <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
        <span class="preheader" style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">Welcome</span>
        <table class="main" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; background: #ffffff; border-radius: 3px;">

          <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
          <tr>
            <td class="wrapper" style="vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; ">
                <tr>
                  <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <a href="#"><%= image_tag "/images/logo.png", width: 94, height: 40 %></a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #9f9f9f; font-size: 32px;  font-weight: bolder; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;"> Welcome <span style="color: #317EAC;"> <%= @user.username %></span></p>
                    <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;">You have successfully signed up as a user.</p>
                    <br>
                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #317eac; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;"> <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #317eac; border: solid 1px #317eac; border-radius: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #317EAC;">Sign-in</a> </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
        </table>

        <!-- START FOOTER -->
        <div class="footer" style="clear: both; Margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
              <td class="content-block" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;">
                <span class="apple-link" style="color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;"></span>
                <br>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->

        <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
      </div>
   </td>
    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u post mailer and view template?

Comment: Thanks for the reply 7urkm3n , I just updated my question with both the mailer action and the the view template.